# css box 'skips' on second line

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float

Within a WordPress plugin (own creation) I want to position some WooCommerce category images... but there something strange happens.

Each category box is defined more or less in the following way :

```
<div class="edu-cat-item">
    <a href="/someurl/"><img src="some-image.jpg></a>
    <a href="/someurl/">Title of the cat</a>
</div>
```

In the CSS the boxes are made to float to the left...

```
.edu-cat-item {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   width: 175px;
   float: left;
   padding:10px;
}

edu-cat-item img {
   border-width:2px;
   border-style:solid;

}

.edu-cat-item a {
   text-align:center;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;

}
```

And -not really a surprise-  it works... HOWEVER!

The customer wants the selected category to have an orange border.

So in the PHP code an extra class is added to one specific item... The HTML becomes :

```
<div class="edu-cat-item  edu-sub-select">
    <a href="/someurl/"><img src="some-image.jpg></a>
    <a href="/someurl/">Title of the cat</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS gets an additional :

```
.edu-sub-select img {
    border-color: #ff9900!important;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

And now strange things happen... when it is more than one row, the second row 'indents' one position behind the selected cat... Would love to post images but I need 'reputation 10' to do so...

However willing to share them by mail.

Comment: put images on something like imigur and then put link to them in question

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a quotation mark:

```
<a href="/someurl/"><img src="some-image.jpg></a>
```

Maybe that's just an error in posting the question though.  Could you create a jsfiddle showing the problem, it's hard to understand what you mean by "indent"

---

By the way, you might want to try getting rid of `float:left;` and replacing with `display:inline-block;`.  I avoid the unpredictable behavior of `float` wherever possible.

---

Was curious so I made a simplified fiddle myself: http://jsfiddle.net/bca1m1n2/

What's happening is that the border causes the height of the orange element to be taller than the rest.  When a floated element goes to the next line, it positions itself against the orange element because the orange element is taller.  Behavior seems strange, but is correct - so don't use floats for alignment :)

So if you give `.edu-cat-item` a fixed height, that also solves the problem

```
.edu-cat-item {
   width: 175px;
   height:100px;
   float:left;
}
```

Cool question OP

Comment: Yes, the closing quote was a mistake from my side... the original code is all PHP, so I wanted to 'unclutter' it by giving an example of the intended output. In the original code the quote closes and the missing dot is also a copy error: The problem is not that the box does not show, but that in the line blow the boxes do not start left, but one position further as the marke box. However the display:inline-block sounds interesting and I'll try it tomorrow (now time for me to hit my bed).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to what Kurt Serge wrote, you could use an outline instead of a border. This way your "border" (outline) does not affect the flow of items.
Here's a little definition of CSS outlines from MDN / W3C (they write the same thing):

> Outlines do not take up space

MDN adds the following detail:

> they are drawn above the content.

So your css would look like this:

```
.edu-sub-select img {
  outline-color: #ff9900!important;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: 2px;
}
```